# Clicking "edit tags" twice causes two and a half tag boxes

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tags

If you click "edit tags" twice (You have to be pretty fast), you end up with two and a half tag boxes.

http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/332/tagging.jpg

Comment: i can confirm the behavior, but i think the simplest fix is *"Don't do that"* ...

Comment: freehand... oval! :)

Comment: @quack Do you know how hard it is doing a single click 25 coffees into the day?

Comment: @quack: That's how you can *fix* every bug ...

Comment: you've only had 25 cups?  that's like half my daily supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good find - this will be fixed in the next deployment.